# c# How to select distinct items from objects using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I would like to select only the distinct usernames and id from the query. Currently, it is returning duplicates.

```
                  TotalUsers = (from p in reports
                                   group p by new
                                   {
                                       p.UserID,
                                       p.UserName
                                   } into grp
                                   select new Employee()
                                   {
                                       Name = grp.Key.UserName,
                                       Id = grp.Key.UserID
                                   }).ToList();
```

I tried doing `Name = grp.Key.UserName.First().ToString()` but this gives me the first letter of the username.

Current Output Example:

```
{UserID=1,UserName="N1"}
{UserID=2,UserName="N2"}
{UserID=1,UserName="N1"}
{UserID=2,UserName="N2"}
```

Desired Output:

```
 {UserID=1,UserName="N1"}
 {UserID=2,UserName="N2"}
```

Comment: updated the comment.

Comment: Hi @HJ1990, take a look at the second part of my answer, it does exactly what you want. The problem is that dynamic objects have no definition of equals, so the group by is not working: if not Equals is defined they are all different

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is really hard to answer without knowing what your `reports` objects look like, and having a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

I'm making the assumption that `UserID` is a unique identifier for the user. And that the `UserName` will always correspond with the `UserID`. If so, the following should give you the distinct users...

```
TotalUsers = reports.GroupBy(x => x.UserID)
    .Select(x => x.First())
    .Select(x => new Employee()
                               {
                                   Name = x.UserName,
                                   Id = x.UserID
                               })
    .ToList();
```

The `GroupBy` will collate all of the items with the same `UserID`. Then we select the first of those items - this is entirely arbitrary, and without knowing why you are getting duplicates, this may not be the best solution - *it may be worth looking into why you are getting duplicates, rather than solving the problem here*. Then each of these is converted into an `Employee` object.

Answer (score 1):

Let's assume your key (for users) is ID and that you have this DataSet:

```
Report
ID    |  UserID    |    UserName

1     |  1         |    UN1
2     |  2         |    UN2
3     |  3         |    UN1
```

Than, when you want distinct couples of (UserID, UserName) you will have the UserName UN1 twice, once for ID 1 and once for ID 3. The only way to go around it is to ignore the UserID. It means that you have to change to code in this way:

```
TotalUsers = (from p in reports
                               group p by new
                               {
                                   p.UserName
                               } into grp
                               select new Employee()
                               {
                                   Name = grp.Key.UserName
                               }).ToList();
```

**Right Answer - EDIT AFTER EXAMPLES GIVEN**

If that was not the case and your problem is that your query is returning twice the couple (1, UN1) from the following dataset:

```
Report
ID    |  UserID    |    UserName

1     |  1         |    UN1
2     |  2         |    UN2
3     |  3         |    UN1
4     |  1         |    UN1
```

it is not working because of a missing "Equals" method. You can solve it this way:

```
public class UserData{
     public string UserName {get;set;}
     public string UserId {get;set;}

     public override bool Equals(object x) {
        if (! (x is UserData)) return false;
        UserData y = (UserData) x;
        return this.UserName == x.UserName && this.UserId == x.UserId;
     }
}

TotalUsers = (from p in reports
                               group p by new UserData
                               {
                                   UserId = p.UserId,
                                   UserName = p.UserName
                               } into grp
                               select new Employee()
                               {
                                   Name = grp.Key.UserName,
                                   Id = grp.Key.UserId
                               }).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm  creating group and its key contains `$"{p.UserID}-{p.UserName}"` and it will make sure its unique

```
TotalUsers = (from p in  new List<User>()
              group p by $"{p.UserID}-{p.UserName}"
                   into grp
              select new Employee()
              {
                  Name = grp.First().UserName,
                  Id = grp.First().UserID
              }).ToList();
```

Comment: get it from the key or from the first element it's the same thing no?

Comment: group by key, and get first element of that group.

Comment: sorry, the key here is string, but for the posted code in the question, get userName from key or from the irst element, it's the same thing.